# How can I make my Apple Watch app work without an iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

When my iPhone is not available, my WatchKit app on the Apple Watch does not work (a red crossed-out iPhone symbol appears). How can I make my app work without the iPhone? How do I tell it to use data that is cached on my Apple Watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, because this is not how Apple Watch apps work at the moment. Your watch app does not run on the watch, it runs on the iPhone but displays its UI on the watch. When the phone isn't nearby, there's no place to run the code.

Apple has said that stand-alone watch apps will be possible this summer. Probably they'll announce it at WWDC in June.